# Support for SSL Client Authentication in phantomjs

Tags: ssl, phantomjs

This commit: [support for SSL Client Authentication](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/54a54dc0687a4b93562285d4f632dcafe2c7bf4f) ...tells us there is a certificate flag to play with...

My attempt:

```
phantomjs main.js \
  --ssl-protocol=any \
  --ssl-client-certificate-file=/tmp/joppli/data/certificate/certificado.crt \
  --ssl-client-key-file=/tmp/joppli/data/certificate/certificado.key \
  --ssl-client-key-passphrase=foobar \
  --web-security=false
```

What ever I try however, I can't access the page. I get:

```
page.onLoadFinished
arguments[0] = "fail"
```

Is the above command correct? Why does it fail? How can I debug what's wrong? (the `fail` message leaves much to desire)

The page I'm trying to access is: https://www.sedecatastro.gob.es/
With out the ssl: http://www.sedecatastro.gob.es/ it works just fine though.

I can't however access some parts of this webpage with out a specific certificate:

- https://www.sedecatastro.gob.es/OVCFrames.aspx?TIPO=TIT
- https://www.sedecatastro.gob.es/Accesos/SECAccTitular.aspx?Dest=20

Answer (score 1):

The HTTPS version of the site isn't providing its entire chain of TLS certificates, which causes phantomjs to fail on an untrusted certificate. Try adding `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` to your command line, and see if that works. If so, the proper solution will be to download the intermediate CA's certificate, and then tell phantomjs to trust it with `--ssl-certificates-path=/path/to/ca.pem`.

The certificate you need is available at https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/ec503507b215c4956219e2a89a5b42992c4c2c20.pem, and further diagnostics are available at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sedecatastro.gob.es